# Horizontal ScrollView with left and right children showing a little

Tags: android, xml, layout

How to make this type of scroll view in android, which shows next and previous item a little?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [DiscreteScrollView](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Well, By using this code. It'll working fine.**

```
disCreateScrollView.setItemTransformer(new ScaleTransformer.Builder()
                .setMaxScale(1.15f)
                .setMinScale(0.8f)
                .setPivotX(Pivot.X.CENTER) // CENTER is a default one
                .setPivotY(Pivot.Y.BOTTOM) // CENTER is a default one
                .build());
```

**By setMinScale(float) it'll set Non-Select item size**

**By setMaxScale(float) it'll set Selected item size**